# Subset of a data frame with the penultimate values of one of the columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with lots of columns, one of them has the code of the sample area and another one has the number of the sample. I want to subset the information just from the penultimate sample in each sample area. I've tried many different things...in the end this is my best guess...but it's still not working.

```
site <- sample (1:3, 10, replace= T)
d2 <- sample (1:5, 10, replace= T)
d3 <- sample (1:5, 10, replace= T)
samplet <- sample (1:4, 10, replace= T)
mydata <- data.frame (cbind(site, d2, d3, samplet))

penultimate <- matrix(NA,,) # here I dont know how the return will be, as I dont know    how the dataframe will change
si <- matrix (NA, , )  
pl <- unique (site)
for (i in 1:(length (pl))) {
    si <-  mydata[which (samplet==pl[i]),] # I tried to create a temporary matrix, so I can calculate each site at a time
    penultimate <- si[which (si$samplet!=(max(si$samplet[si$samplet!=max(si$samplet)]))),]
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: there's no `d1` or `d4` in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `tapply` using @Ricardo's data:

```
# data (thanks @Ricardo)
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- data.frame(d1=strsplit("AAABBCCCCCDD", "")[[1]], 
             d2=rnorm(12), d3=LETTERS[1:12], 
             d4=c(101:103, 201:202, 301:305, 401:402))

# solution
idx <- unlist(tapply(seq_len(nrow(mydata)), mydata$d1, function(x) x[length(x)-1]))
mydata[idx, ]
#    d1         d2 d3  d4
# 2   A  0.2774292  B 102
# 4   B -2.3456977  D 201
# 9   C -0.5644520  I 304
# 11  D -0.4771927  K 401
```

The `unlist` is required in case there's just 1 row for a particular value for `id1`.

---

#### What does the code do?

I'll explain as good as I can by breaking the function. Looking at the line `idx <- ...`, the function `tapply` splits the sequence `c(1, 2, ... nrow(mydata))` (here, `nrow(mydata) = 12`) by the column `mydata$d1`. That is:

```
tapply(1:12, mydata$d1, c) # just to show what happens here
$A
[1] 1 2 3

$B
[1] 4 5

$C
[1]  6  7  8  9 10

$D
[1] 11 12
```

Now, instead of the function `c` we need the *last-but-one* element of each of these elements. So, we create a `function(x) x[length(x)-1]` where each of these `A, B, C, D` is passed one by one and the code `x[length(x)-1]` selects the *last-but-one* element **each time**. These give you the *row index* of *all* penultimate rows. So, just subset the data.frame by `mydata[idx, ]`.

Comment: sorry my lack of understanding of the R language.. but where did you deterimine that you want the penultimate of the column 4?

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation! It's really helpful! I still don't understand how do you especify that you are classifing by a certain column, the column d4 for example.

Comment: Yes, but lets say that I want to get the last-but-one of column d4 from each group of collumn d1.. how can I specify that? I can clearly see that you did that in your example, but still hard to figure out how to apply in my data! Cheers!

Comment: Thank you @Arun, I didn't understand before that `seq_len(nrow(mydata)` is to select the last collumn! Now I can change this and apply to any other collumn of my data.frame! So I have `idx` but I still can get my subset based on the information of `idx`, when I do `mydata[idx, ]`I get the fist lines of the matrix, where the number of lines is = to the length of `idx`. I'll looking at how to use `match ()` but still not clear for me how to do it with information from `idx` that contain information from two vectors. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

A simple way is to use `data.table` and its built in `.N` value

```
# assuming `d1` is the column from which you want to find the penultimate

mydata <- data.frame(d1=strsplit("AAABBCCCCCDD", "")[[1]], d2=rnorm(12), d3=LETTERS[1:12], d4=c(101:103, 201:202, 301:305, 401:402))

DT <- data.table(mydata)

DT[, .SD[.N-1], by=d1]

   d1         d2 d3  d4
1:  A  1.6906714  B 102
2:  B -0.1239458  D 201
3:  C -0.2976339  I 304
4:  D  0.6858120  K 401
```

#### Compare with mydata

```
> mydata
   d1         d2 d3  d4
1   A  0.5986002  A 101
2   A  1.6906714  B 102   <~~~~  \
3   A -0.3253657  C 103
4   B -0.1239458  D 201   <~~~~   -\
5   B  0.8261401  E 202
6   C  0.0601318  F 301             Penultimate Values by d1
7   C -0.9766622  G 302
8   C  0.1028259  H 303
9   C -0.2976339  I 304   <~~~~~  -/ 
10  C -1.1467000  J 305
11  D  0.6858120  K 401   <~~~~~  / 
12  D -0.6160335  L 402
```

***edit, updated with new sample data.***

Comment: Thank you Ricardo, but the problem is not to access the penultimate value of a column but to do for each level of the other column. E.g. I need to calculate the penultimate value of colunm d4 for each level of the column d1.

Comment: @Arun, sorry, I forgot to set a seed, but look at the values of `d3`

Comment: @user2335669, they are for `R`, but it is using `data.table` instead of `data.frame`s.   Run `install.packages("data.table")` if needed

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers, it is also possible to do this with `dplyr`:

```
set.seed(1234)
mydata <- data.frame(d1=strsplit("AAABBCCCCCDD", "")[[1]], 
                 d2=rnorm(12), d3=LETTERS[1:12], 
                 d4=c(101:103, 201:202, 301:305, 401:402))

require(dplyr)

mydata %.%                 
  group_by(d1) %.% 
  mutate(count = 1:n()) %.% 
  filter(count %in% max(c(count-1,1))) %.%   
  select(-count)
```

As in @BondedDust's answer i assume you use the solitary row if there is only one row for any given d1 "group"